# ¿Cómo creo un AJAX para llamar a una función de javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el cual me ha surgido una complicación. Estoy creando en el documento php una función de javascript (quiero mezclar ambos elementos) para realizar un procedimiento almacenado dentro de una función que pueda llamar cuando lo necesite. He investigado y he llegado a la conclusión de que necesito usar un AJAX para esto ya que lo que estoy intentando hacer es una pieza de código javascript que llame a una pieza de código php. Pero aún soy nuevo en el tema de los AJAX y no comprendo muy bien como funcionan así que agradecería si alguien pudiese echarme una mano.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function miFuncion(){
        var objXMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        objXMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(objXMLHttpRequest.readyState === 4) {
                if(objXMLHttpRequest.status === 200) {
                    alert(objXMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    <?php
                    $db->query("CALL miProcedimiento(" . $variable_php['datos_mySQL'] . "," . variableJavascript . ",@salida);");
                    ?>
                } else {
                    alert('Error Code: ' +  objXMLHttpRequest.status);
                    alert('Error Message: ' + objXMLHttpRequest.statusText);
                }
            }
        }
        objXMLHttpRequest.open('GET', 'request_ajax_data.php');
        objXMLHttpRequest.send();
    }
</script>
```

La mayor parte de ese código lo he sacado de páginas y ejemplos pero no se muy bien como funciona (como ya he dicho soy nuevo en estas cosas). He introducido mi procedimiento almacenado pero siempre da error y dice que la función no está definida. Pongo el error a continuación

> Uncaught ReferenceError: miFuncion is not defined at miOtraFuncion (script.js:227) at script.js:145

Si alguien sabe como arreglarlo o si hay otras formas de hacerlo se agradecería la ayuda.

Comment: `async function miFuncion(){ const res = await fetch('request_ajax_data.php'); const text = await res.text(); }`

Answer (score 0):

La página "request_ajax_data.php" debe recibir "variableJavascript" como parámetro, realizar la consulta, y devolver el resultado, que recogerá la función indicada en "objXMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange".
Un ejemplo podría ser algo parecido a esto:

```
<div id="resultado"></div>
<script>
    var variableJS="";

    var objXMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    objXMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(objXMLHttpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            if(objXMLHttpRequest.status === 200) {
                resultado.innerHTML=objXMLHttpRequest.responseText;
            } else {
                alert('Error Code: ' +  objXMLHttpRequest.status);
                alert('Error Message: ' + objXMLHttpRequest.statusText);
            }
        }
    }
    objXMLHttpRequest.open('GET', 'a.php?v='+variableJS);
    objXMLHttpRequest.send();

</script>
```

Y el PHP (en este ejemplo "a.php"):

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['v'])) {
        $variable=$_GET['v'];
        // Filtrar $variable para evitar valores inesperados.
        $salida = $db->query("CALL miProcedimiento(" . $variable_php['datos_mySQL'] . "," . $variable . ",@salida);");
        echo ($salida);
    }
    exit;
?>
```

Evidentemente falta el resto de tu código PHP donde declaras $db, etc.